# BASE_OFFSET macro from Essential COM

Tags: c++, com, macros

I am reading Essential COM and encountered a macro 'BASE_OFFSET' from chapter 2 of the book and I don't really understand its syntax or why it's done that way.

```
#define BASE_OFFSET(ClassName, BaseName) \
(DWORD_PTR(static_cast<BaseName*>(reinterpret_cast<ClassName*>(0x10000000))) - 0x10000000)
```

Can anyone explain this macro and how we use this? In fact, the book uses this macro but since I don't really understand it, I don't see the practical usage of it. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: By the way another standard windows macro [FIELD_OFFSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545727(v=vs.85).aspx) get you offset of the named field of the structure.

Comment: you are welcome! By the way it's defined so `#define FIELD_OFFSET(type, field)    ((LONG)(LONG_PTR)&(((type *)0)->field))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The macro makes up a dummy pointer to `ClassName` with the `reinterpret_cast` and then casts it to the `BaseName` with the `static_cast`.

In the presence of multiple inheritance, the address of a base class subobject is not always the same as the address of the object. This possibly-different-address is subtracted from the original dummy address, to obtain the offset of the `BaseName` subobject in a `ClassName` object. It's similar to `offsetof`, but for base class subobjects instead of members.

[image: Diagram showing an example]

This is only useful if you're doing some nasty low-level stuff.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. Your diagram helps me to visualize what goes on.